# How to get Release Hash key Facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key, release

Hi I have problem in getting release hash key

I have downloaded the openssl and put it in c drive. how can i get the release hash key for my android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have the keytool exe

You can find this in your `Java JRE Bin folder`. As an example

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin

You want to run this command. Replace `C:\Users\someotherlocation\yourkeystorefile.keystore` with your keystore location. Make sure the Open SSL location is correct too.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\someotherlocation\yourkeystorefile.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```